# How do I find and display CaseParty address?

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to loop in the xml document below, and display the (Address) `/Integration/Case/CaseParty/Address` where  `/Integration/Case/CaseParty/Connection[@Word="DFD"]`.

If the `/Integration/Case/CaseParty/Address` is not found where `CaseParty/Connection[@Word="DFD"]`, I would like to check the Address under `PartyID` i.e `/Integration/Party/Address[@PartyCurrent="true"]` and display that one instead.

Here is my xml document

```
<Integration xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:tsg="http://tsgweb.com" xmlns:IXML="http://tsgweb.com" xmlns:CMCodeQueryHelper="urn:CMCodeQueryHelper" PackageID="DL Notice to DVS" MessageID="67084533" xmlns="">
<Case Op="E" InternalID="1617088326" ID="12120229" xmlns:user="http://tylertechnologies.com">
    <CaseParty ID="16731290" InternalCasePartyID="1634787102" InternalPartyID="1614631672">
        <Connection Word="DFD" BaseConnection="DF" ID="36370323" InternalCasePartyConnectionID="1636469444">
            <Description>Defendant</Description>
        </Connection>
        <Address CaseCorrespondence="true" ID="17875824" Type="Standard">
            <AddressLine2>3712 Testing RD</AddressLine2>
            <AddressLine4>St Paul, NY, 21457</AddressLine4>
            <Block>3712</Block>
            <Street>Testing</Street>
            <AddrSfxKy Word="RD">Road</AddrSfxKy>
            <City>St Paul</City>
            <State>NY</State>
            <Zip>21457</Zip>
            <Foreign>false</Foreign>
            <TimestampCreate>5/27/2015 10:34:08 AM</TimestampCreate>
        </Address>
        <TimestampCreate>1/29/2015 5:04:53 PM</TimestampCreate>
        <TimestampChange/>
    </CaseParty>
</Case>
<Party ID="16731290" InternalPartyID="1614631672">
    <Address PartyCorrespondence="true" PartyCurrent="true" ID="17867956" Type="Standard">
        <AddressLine2>1906 3RD AVE S #36</AddressLine2>
        <AddressLine4>Denver, CO, 55408</AddressLine4>
        <Block>1906</Block>
        <Street>3RD AVE S #36</Street>
        <City>Denver</City>
        <State>CO</State>
        <Zip>87459</Zip>
        <Foreign>false</Foreign>
    </Address>
</Party>
```

Desired output should be the NY address.

I am not sure how check Address from both xpaths `/Integration/Case/CaseParty/Address` and `/Integration/Party/Address`

xsl code.

`<xsl:value-of Select="/Integration/Case/CaseParty/Connection[@Word="DFD"]/Address"/>`

Comment: You should note that your XSL code as written above would not work because Address is not a child of Connection, they are siblings.

Answer (score 1):

An XPath returns a node set (or possibly nothing), in your case union them together in such a way to select one. Considering a choice like this:

rule1 | rule2[not(rule1)]

you would always get rule1 if it passes, or rule2 (if it passes) or nothing if both do not pass.

rule1 = /Integration/Case/CaseParty/Address[preceding-sibling::Connection[@Word='DFD']]

rule2 = /Integration/Party/Address[@PartyCurrent='true']

```
(/Integration/Case/CaseParty/Address[preceding-sibling::Connection[@Word='DFD']] | /Integration/Party/Address[@PartyCurrent='true'][not(/Integration/Case/CaseParty/Address[preceding-sibling::Connection[@Word='DFD']])])[1]
```

Note that I added the [1] predicate at the end as I do not know whether you could have multiple Addresses in each case. You only need it if it is possible in your data so as to not return multiple nodes.

Comment: You have two conceptual mistakes, which may not affect the result in this case, but are important enough to point out. First, the `|` operator does not *concatenate* (two strings) - it returns the **union of two node-sets**. Second, you cannot union two sets "in order of importance"; nodes will appear in the union in the same order in which they appear in the original document.

Comment: I agree with you Michael. Kevin code only work when `Address` is under `/Integration/Case/CaseParty/Address`. Otherwise when `Address` is under `/Integration/Party/Address` the code fails. How can I modify it to make it work?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I will modify answer ... the basic premise would be to write "rule1" | "rule2[not(rule1]" so that they are exclusive of eachother.

Comment: Thank you @michael.hor257k. Although I am not clear what you mean by strings, I know they are nodesets, you are correct about document order. I have modified above answer.

Comment: I meant that the term "concatenate" is generally used to describe a string manipulation.

Comment: Understood, that is what I thought so I changed that to union above.

Answer (score 1):

A simple, if verbose method would be to use `xsl:choose`, along the lines of:

```
<xsl:variable name="primary-address" select="path/to/primary/address" />
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$primary-address">
        <xsl:value-of select="$primary-address"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="path/to/secondary/address"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

or in XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:variable name="primary-address" select="path/to/primary/address" />
<xsl:value-of select="if($primary-address) then $primary-address else path/to/secondary/address"/>
```